# Why (listings) ⟨language⟩s' ⟨dialect⟩s are taken in account with \lstset{alsolanguage=...} but not with \lstloadlanguages{...}?

Tags: listings

A (`listings`) `⟨language⟩`'s `⟨dialect⟩` is taken in account:

- with `\lstset{alsolanguage=[⟨dialect⟩]⟨language⟩}`,
- but not with `\lstloadlanguages{[⟨dialect⟩]⟨language⟩}`.

This is shown by the following MCE where:

- `\def` is control sequence from the `TeX` language,
- `\LoadClass` is control sequence from the `AlLaTeX` dialect of the `TeX` language.

Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  language=TeX,
  texcsstyle=*\color{red},
}

\begin{document}
\lstloadlanguages{[AlLaTeX]TeX}

\begin{lstlisting}
\def
\LoadClass
\end{lstlisting}

\lstset{alsolanguage=[AlLaTeX]TeX}

\begin{lstlisting}
\def
\LoadClass
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: because `lstloadlanguages` **loads** languages instead of use them...?

Comment: @user202729 You may be right since the documentation says that `alsolanguage` “activates a (dialect of a) programming language in addition to the current active one.” But I wonder what's the benefit of `\lstloadlanguages`.

Comment: I think the docs say preload faster than load on demand or something.

Comment: @user202729 OK but what's loading on demand? And what's the difference between (1) “loading“ and “preloading”, (2) (pre)loading and activating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting `listings` package documentation:

> After package loading it is recommend[ed] to load all used dialects of programming
> languages with the following command. It is faster to load several languages with
> one command than loading each language on demand.
>
> ```
> \lstloadlanguages{⟨comma separated list of languages⟩}
> ```
>
> Each language is of the form `[⟨dialect⟩]⟨language⟩`. Without the optional
> `[⟨dialect⟩]` the package loads a default dialect. So write `[Visual]C++` if
> you want Visual C++ and `[ISO]C++` for ISO C++. Both together can be
> loaded by the command `\lstloadlanguages{[Visual]C++,[ISO]C++}`.

Essentially, `\lstloadlanguages` does nothing other than declaring all the languages that is going to be used in the document (and for a speedup, as the documentation claims).

You still need the `lstset` (or specify the language directly in the `lstlistings` blocks with `[language={...}]`) to use it.

Comment: In such as case, the comment from Heiko Oberdiek [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130241/18401) doesn't apply anymore?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I think it means that it does apply? That's an example where declaring things (in the correct order) speeds up the loading

Comment: Sorry but I don't see your point. Could elaborate with examples, one slower than the other?